# Additional (not imported) dependencies for Remix site deploy to Netlify required?

Tags: reactjs, netlify, remix, pnpm, netlify-function

I'm currently trying to deploy a Remix App to Netlify and followed [the steps described in the Netlify docs](https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/frameworks/remix/).
However, as soon as I try to deploy the site (`netlify deploy`), Netlify complains about some missing dependencies I never directly imported into my project.

```
// e.g. 
Error: In file "C:\..\PROJECT_NAME\.netlify\functions-internal\server.js"
Cannot find module '@react-hook/debounce'
```

I would be fine to add one or two deps, but it seems like I've to add 10+ deps.
So I guess it has a deeper reason I couldn't figure out yet.

[image]

Note: The green marked deps I had already to add, and I'm still not finished.
The next dep I'm supposed to add is `@react-hook/debounce`. Then I will run `pnpm install -D @react-hook/debounce` and `netlify deploy`, wait `20s` and it will complain about the next missing dependency, and so on.

I set up a new project from scratch following [this tutorial](https://www.netlify.com/blog/how-to-use-tailwind-css-with-remix/).
However, there occurs the same issue as described above.

I'm using `pnpm` as package manager. As described in [this blog](https://www.netlify.com/blog/how-to-use-pnpm-with-netlify-build/) Netlify claims to support `pnpm` out of the box.

#### Useful Resources (from the new setup project)

`netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "pnpm run build"
  publish = "public"

[dev]
  command = "remix watch"
  port = 3000

[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/.netlify/functions/server"
  status = 200

[[headers]]
  for = "/build/*"
  [headers.values]
    "Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=31536000, s-maxage=31536000"
```

`package.json` (without added deps)

```
{
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "pnpm run build:css && remix build",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -m -i ./styles/app.css -o app/styles/app.css",
    "dev": "concurrently \"pnpm run dev:css\" \"remix dev\"",
    "dev:css": "tailwindcss -w -i ./styles/app.css -o app/styles/app.css"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@netlify/functions": "^1.0.0",
    "@remix-run/netlify": "^1.7.3",
    "@remix-run/node": "^1.7.3",
    "@remix-run/react": "^1.7.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@remix-run/dev": "^1.7.3",
    "@remix-run/eslint-config": "^1.7.3",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^1.7.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "concurrently": "^7.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14"
  }
}
```

`remix.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig} */
module.exports = {
  serverBuildTarget: "netlify",
  server:
    process.env.NETLIFY || process.env.NETLIFY_LOCAL
      ? "./server.js"
      : undefined,
  ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*"],
  // appDirectory: "app",
  // assetsBuildDirectory: "public/build",
  // serverBuildPath: ".netlify/functions-internal/server.js",
  // publicPath: "/build/",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred because `pnpm` has another `node_modules` structure than `yarn` or `npm` which `Netlify` currently can't handle.
Luckily `pnpm` offers a flag `--shamefully-hoist` which
creates a flat `node_modules` structure, similar to that of `npm` or `yarn`.

-> To resolve the issue, you need to run your pnpm install with `--shamefully-hoist`. So, simply add the Environment Variable `PNPM_FLAGS` with the value `--shamefully-hoist` to your `netlify.toml` config.

```
// ..

[build.environment]
  PNPM_FLAGS = "--shamefully-hoist"

// ..
```

Further details:
https://answers.netlify.com/t/nuxt-3-deploy-failed-rollup-failed-to-resolve-import-vue/77680/9

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is using ESM packages, see [Remix docs: Gotchas](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/pages/gotchas#importing-esm-packages)

Adding

```
/** @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig} */
module.exports = {
  serverDependenciesToBundle: ["@react-hook/debounce"],
  // ...
};
```

to remix.config.js could help